# How to concat 2 arrays, based on index

Tags: javascript

I would like to merge 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = [["apple"], ["banana", "cherry"]]
arr2 = ["id1", "id2"]
```

I would like to get the output like:

```
result = [["apple id1"], ["banana id2", "cherry id2"]]
```

or

```
result = [["apple from id1"], ["banana from id2", "cherry from id2"]]
```

I have tried concat, but this is not keeping me the ID for each element.
I am new in development overall, and I didn't find so far any results that would give me the proper output.
Any hint how can I do this?

Comment: Is your second array always an array of indexes ?

Comment: Something like arr1[0][0]+" "+arr2[0] ?

Comment: @UtsavPatel: my second array contains some strings and it should be some category, from where items in arr1 are part of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#map` is what you need.

```js
arr1 = [["apple"], ["banana", "cherry"]]
arr2 = ["id1", "id2"]

var result = arr2.map((id, idx) => {
  return arr1[idx].map(item => item + " from " + id);
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map the new items.

```js
var arr1 = [["apple"], ["banana", "cherry"]],
    arr2 = ["id1", "id2"],
    result = arr1.map((a, i) => a.map(v => [v, arr2[i]].join(' ')));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A function like this would work

```js
function concat(arr1, arr2) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) {
            arr1[i][j] += ` ${arr2[i]}`;
        }
    }

    return arr1;
}
```

You can execute it like

```js
concat([["apple"], ["banana", "cherry"]], ["id1", "id2"])
```

**Note:** this modifies arr1, because it's passed as reference. You could change this so it uses a copy of it instead if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop and adds "from" to the result.

```js
arr1 = [["apple"], ["banana", "cherry"]];
arr2 = ["id1", "id2"];


for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
  
  arr1[i] = arr1[i].join() + " from " + arr2[i]

}

console.log(arr1);
```